# Converting XGBoost model to CoreML

Tags: python, ios, xgboost, coreml

I am trying to convert the following XGBoost model to a CoreML File but I get the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
  packages/coremltools/converters/xgboost/_tree.py", line 48, in convert
return _MLModel(_convert_tree_ensemble(model, feature_names, target))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/coremltools/converters/xgboost/_tree_ensemble.py", line 111, in convert_tree_ensemble
xgb_model_str = model.get_dump(with_stats=True, dump_format = 'json')
TypeError: get_dump() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dump_format'
```

I installed xgboost using pip. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Install supported xgboost version - it is 0.6 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the version of xgboost 0.61 and I moved to 0.81 and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation guide. Do not use pip install xgboost or you will get this error with get_dump. See http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html for more information.